# MSVC constexpr function 'xyz' cannot result in a constant expression

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

I've made a function that concatenates multiple smaller values into one larger value while preserving the bianry representation of the values (ex. to build an `int argb` from multiple `unsigned char r, g, b, a`). I know I can also achive this by bit shifting the values but that's not the matter of this question.

However, if I use the function to actually generate an integer from those values, msvc throws a compiler error:

```
error C3615: constexpr function 'Color::operator int' cannot result in a constant expression
note: failure was caused by call of undefined function or one not declared 'constexpr'
note: see usage of '<lambda_dcb9c20fcc2050e56c066522a838749d>::operator ()'
```

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/P5X_xS) is a complete sample. Clang and gcc compile the code but msvc refuses:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

namespace detail
{
    template <typename From, typename To, size_t Size>
    union binary_fusion_helper
    {
        const From from[Size];
        const To to;
    };

    template <typename To, typename Arg, typename ...Args, typename = std::enable_if_t<(... && std::is_same_v<std::remove_reference_t<Arg>, std::remove_reference_t<Args>>)>>
    constexpr To binary_fusion(Arg arg, Args... args)
    {
        using in_t = std::remove_reference_t<Arg>;
        using out_t = To;
        static_assert(sizeof(out_t) == sizeof(in_t) * (sizeof...(Args) + 1), "The target type must be of exact same size as the sum of all argument types.");
        constexpr size_t num = sizeof(out_t) / sizeof(in_t);
        return binary_fusion_helper<in_t, out_t, num> { std::forward<Arg>(arg), std::forward<Args>(args)... }.to;
    }
}

template <typename To>
constexpr auto binary_fusion = [](auto ...values) -> To
{
    return detail::binary_fusion<std::remove_reference_t<To>>(values...);
};

struct Color
{
    float r, g, b, a;

    explicit constexpr operator int() const noexcept
    {
        return binary_fusion<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(r * 255), static_cast<unsigned char>(g * 255),
                                  static_cast<unsigned char>(b * 255), static_cast<unsigned char>(a * 255));
    }
};
```

Do clang and gcc just ignore that the code will never run as a constexpr or is msvc wrong? And if msvc is correct, why can't the function run at compile time?

Comment: Which version of MSVC are you using?

Comment: @Hiroki the very latest. Not sure which one it is, can't access my computer atm.

Comment: You have to use shifting instead of union.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Every compiler is correct. The rule in [[dcl.constexpr]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#5) is:

> For a constexpr function or constexpr constructor that is neither defaulted nor a template, if no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function or constructor could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression, or, for a constructor, a constant initializer for some object ([basic.start.static]), the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

There is no set of arguments you can pass in to `binary_fusion` that would allow it to be evaluated as a core constant expression, so declaring it `constexpr` is ill-formed, NDR. The reason this is the case is because `detail::binary_fusion()` initializes a union with one active member and then reads from the inactive member, which you are not allowed to do in constant expressions ([[expr.const]/4.8](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#4.8)):

> an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion that is applied to a glvalue that refers to a non-active member of a union or a subobject thereof;

MSVC somehow diagnoses this, gcc/clang happen not to. All compilers correctly diagnose this:

```
constexpr Color c{1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
constexpr int i = static_cast<int>(c); // error: not a constant expression
```

Comment: Wow! "lvalue-to-rvalue conversion that is applied to a glvalue... " that... is not something mere mortals would get is happening here.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk It translates roughly to "actually reading it".