# Is a char array member initialization with a string literal constexpr?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

The following code compiles with gcc and clang, but not with msvc. For msvc the initialization of the char array member variable with a string literal seems to result in the implicitly generated default constructor not being constexpr according to the compiler:

```
struct S
{
#if 1
    char str[2] = "1";
#else
    char str[2] { 'a', '\0'};
#endif
};

int main()
{
    constexpr S s; // line 12: compiler error in msvc
    constexpr S s2{};
}
```

**MSVC output**

```
example.cpp
<source>(12): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
<source>(12): note: failure was caused by call of undefined function or one not declared 'constexpr'
<source>(12): note: see usage of 'S::S'
Compiler returned: 2
```

[See godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEEtIADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgIhYZEsMXFctpj2eQxCBEzEBBk%2BfgF2mA5pNXUEBRHRsfG2tfWNWWUKQ92hvcX9XACUtqhexMjsHOPEXg4A1EImGgCCJgDsVofmAMx4VNtc%2Bwfbj9vICHXbGyYArBZmXwAi2xMFwB5jMdzMvwuZyOZguFSU9yez1exHeBGIXx%2B/0Bp22YA4THxpDxHC%2Bbg0%2BJOfyB0Murmu9ypNMZh1CBG2LCYoQgc0Zp0RTzQDHGmFUCVRQnezMOSKFIrFEvev35x2pUL5fw4C1onE%2BvD8HC0pFQnDc1ms7yWK0wgNhPFIBE0WoWAGt/J8AHQab0%2B32%2B476TiSfVO42cXgKEAaB1OhZwWBIIX8YichirciUNAsBJ0WKR2BZnP0YgASXQKAMRik3uNCSqkY4AFpxuggX9TJZrGYtHHC7nS%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%2BQNWOgzjw1sHjEYXeNBKWAgEl8sTl1icJWDWd6L0%2B77fv%2BsxeA/Ajv1/AqcvEfL%2BEERQVHUWzStITCwoSOL0eejjYM4czfJJ9lUBuGm6eQH6D0ZwGJP7OGEdjWjUfRtipbDDhuOjPGaPRpmXtsrjeKRjzNK6yQgA%3D%3D).

Both using aggregate initialization for the containing object and initializing the array as array of character literals is accepted by all compilers.

Which compiler is right according to the C++ 20 standard?

Comment: what if you write `constexpr S() {}` inside S?

Comment: Related: [MSVC constexpr function 'xyz' cannot result in a constant expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53888313/msvc-constexpr-function-xyz-cannot-result-in-a-constant-expression)

Comment: @user253751 This results in a different error message: `<source>(4): error C3615: constexpr function 'S::S' cannot result in a constant expression
<source>(4): note: failure was caused by a statement or an expression that is not valid in a constexpr context`

Comment: Seems like an obvious MSVC bug, those two declarations are equivalent (if you ignore which value `str[0]` is going to end up with).

Comment: Almost certainly an MSVC bug. Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63558400/10871073